# ¿Cómo se hacen las relaciones entre clases para que el botón me imprima "aaaa"?

Tags: python, pyqt5, model-view-controller

Tengo el botón <kbd>btn_enviar</kbd> creado en la vista , `vista_ui`, lo quiero llamar en el controlador y que me imprima en consola "aaaa" al pulsarlo, pero no me responde no se como hacerlo bien. La vista la he realizado con PyQt5.

Código vista_ui.py:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_vista(object):

    def setupUi(self, vista):

        vista.setObjectName("vista")
        vista.resize(821, 543)
        vista.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(821, 543))
        vista.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(821, 543))
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(vista)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.btn_enviar = QtWidgets.QPushButton(vista)
        self.btn_enviar.setObjectName("btn_enviar")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.btn_enviar, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.txt_busqueda = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(vista)
        self.txt_busqueda.setObjectName("txt_busqueda")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.txt_busqueda, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabla_busqueda = QtWidgets.QTableView(vista)
        self.tabla_busqueda.setObjectName("tabla_busqueda")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.tabla_busqueda, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout_2)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(vista)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(vista)

    def retranslateUi(self, vista):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        vista.setWindowTitle(_translate("vista", "CheckPoint 2"))
        self.btn_enviar.setText(_translate("vista", "Enviar"))

 if __name__ == "__main__":

    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    vista = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_vista()
    ui.setupUi(vista)
    vista.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Código controlador.py:

```
import vista_ui
import modelo
import conexion

class controlador(object):

    def ventana(self):
        vista_ui.btn_enviar.clicked(self.botonEnviar)

    def botonEnviar(self):
        print("aaaaaaaaa")
```

Comment: Creo que tienes un error. ¿No será `clicked` en lugar de `clickec`?

Comment: si , perdon que he pasado la foto sin corregirlo, pero sigue igual. Creo que es un problema con las relaciones entre vistas

Comment: Entonces vas a tener que compartir más código si quieres que te ayuden.

Comment: Por favor no publiques imagenes del código, publica el texto del código (copiar y pegar). Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Tu fallo aquí es el siguiente. Cuando importas `ui_vista` estás importando el módulo `ui_vista` no la clase `Ui_vista` dentro del módulo `ui_vista`. Para solucionarlo, puedes definir la instancia de la clase `Ui_vista` en el contexto global del módulo y luego, importar la instancia desde `controlador.py`:

Código `vista_ui.py`

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

# Añade la futura instancia al contexto global
ui = None

class Ui_vista(object):

    def setupUi(self, vista):

        vista.setObjectName("vista")
        vista.resize(821, 543)
        vista.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(821, 543))
        vista.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(821, 543))
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(vista)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.btn_enviar = QtWidgets.QPushButton(vista)
        self.btn_enviar.setObjectName("btn_enviar")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.btn_enviar, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.txt_busqueda = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(vista)
        self.txt_busqueda.setObjectName("txt_busqueda")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.txt_busqueda, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabla_busqueda = QtWidgets.QTableView(vista)
        self.tabla_busqueda.setObjectName("tabla_busqueda")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.tabla_busqueda, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout_2)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(vista)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(vista)

    def retranslateUi(self, vista):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        vista.setWindowTitle(_translate("vista", "CheckPoint 2"))
        self.btn_enviar.setText(_translate("vista", "Enviar"))

 if __name__ == "__main__":

    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    vista = QtWidgets.QWidget()

    # Sobreescribe la variable global con la instancia
    ui = Ui_vista()
    ui.setupUi(vista)
    vista.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Código `controlador.py`

```py
# Importa la instancia declarada globalmente
from vista_ui import ui as vista_ui
import modelo
import conexion

class controlador(object):

    def ventana(self):
        vista_ui.btn_enviar.clicked.connect(self.botonEnviar)

    def botonEnviar(self):
        print("aaaaaaaaa")
```

Comment: Gracias por esta solución, pero he copiado y pegado tu código tal cuál, pero sigue sin imprimirme la cadena "aaaaaaaaa"

Comment: Vale, acabo de editarlo. Se me olvidó conectar el evento con la función, prueba ahora.

Comment: no me funciona, pero he conseguido resolverlo de otra manera, gracias de todos modos

Answer (score 0):

RESPUESTA

La idea sería crear por un lado el controlador y por otro la vista. 
Según el código inicial en el init de la vista ya espera un controlador, por lo que hay que tenerlo creado antes, por eso lo he agregado en el main con el nombre `micontrolador`. 
De esta forma la vista es la que se va a encargar de asociar los botones a sus funciones, y esto se puede ver en la línea 56, donde al botón en concreto se le asocia la función, ojo hay que tener en cuenta que es si “()” porque sino se le ejecutaría la función.

Código `vista_ui.py`

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
from controlador import Controlador

class MainWindowUIClass(object):

    def __init__(self, controlador):
        super().__init__()
        self.controlador = controlador
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.txt_cadena = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.txt_cadena.setObjectName("txt_cadena")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.txt_cadena)
        self.btn_enviar = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_enviar.setObjectName("btn_enviar")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_enviar)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.tabla_resultados = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabla_resultados.setObjectName("tabla_resultados")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tabla_resultados)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.btn_enviar.clicked.connect(self.controlador.botonEnviar)
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btn_enviar.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enviar"))
def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    micontrolador = Controlador()
    ui = MainWindowUIClass(micontrolador)
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
main()
```

Código `controlador.py`

```
class Controlador:
    def botonEnviar(self):
        print("aaaa")
```

Comment: Esto es una respuesta o una edicion a la pregunta? podes aclararlo?

Comment: Esto es la respuesta a mi propia pregunta.

Comment: Buenisimo!!! Recuerda aceptarla una vez que pasen 24 horas y tambien explica bien como soluciona esto el problema y cual era el problema en tu pregunta. Si es solo codigo sw considera de baja calidad ya que no se entiende cual es la solucion.